# print the result as soon as user input "done"

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, while-loop, user-input

```
largest_so_far = None
smalest_so_far = None

value = float(raw_input(">"))
while value != ValueError:


    value = float(raw_input(">"))
    if value > largest_so_far:      
            largest_so_far = value
    elif value == "done":
        break



print largest_so_far
```

I think problem with this is that done is string while input is float type.

I have also tried it running using `value = raw_input(">")` instead of `float(raw_input(">")` but that prints the result as **done**

Comment: Note that `while value != ValueError:` is **not** going to be effective as exception handling. *"I have also tried it without float but that print result as done!"* - what?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited the question. Hope it will be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few hints:

1. Instead of converting the user input to `float` immediately, why don't you check if it is `done` first?
2. Since you are going to do this forever, until user enters `done` or there is a value error, use an infinite loop and a `try..except`, like this

---

```
# Start with, the negative infinity (the smallest number)
largest_so_far = float("-inf")
# the positive infinity (the biggest number)
smallest_so_far = float("+inf")

# Tell users how they can quit the program
print "Type done to quit the program"

# Infinite loop
while True:

    # Read data from the user
    value = raw_input(">")

    # Check if it is `done` and break out if it actually is
    if value == "done":
        break

    # Try to convert the user entered value to float
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        # If we got `ValueError` print error message and skip to the beginning
        print "Invalid value"
        continue

    if value > largest_so_far:      
        largest_so_far = value

    if value < smallest_so_far:      
        smallest_so_far = value

print largest_so_far
print smallest_so_far
```

---

**Edit:** The edited code has two main problems.

1. The `continue` statement should be within the `except` block. Otherwise, the comparisons are always skipped at all.
2. When you compare two values of different types, Python 2, doesn't complain about it. It simply, compares the type of the values. So, in your case, since you assigned `largest_so_far` as `None`, the `NoneType` is compared with the `float` type.

   ```
   >>> type(None)
   <type 'NoneType'>
   >>> None > 3.14
   False
   >>> None < 3.14
   True
   ```

   Since, the `float` type is always lesser than `None` type, the condition

   ```
   if value > largest_so_far:      
       largest_so_far = value
   ```

   is never met. So you will be getting `None`. Instead, use `float("- inf")` like I have shown in my answer.

Comment: I have updated my code in question, can you please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as follows:

```
largest_so_far = smallest_so_far = None

while True:
    value = raw_input(">")
    # first deal with 'done'
    if value.lower() == 'done':  
        break
    # then convert to float
    try: 
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        continue  # or break, if you don't want to give them another try
    # finally, do comparisons
    if largest_so_far is None or value > largest_so_far:
        largest_so_far = value
    if smallest_so_far is None or value < smallest_so_far:
        smallest_so_far = value
```

Comment: I have updated my code in question, can you please have a look.

Comment: @Freddy 1. Don't change the question once you've had answers. 2. Indentation is important in Python - `continue` should be **in the `except` block**, otherwise the rest of the loop is unreachable.

Comment: sorry for that. And after Indentation it prints largest number but still does not print smallest