# Counting the number of iterations in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

How can we count the number of input given by the user in while loop?

Say user enters 50 numbers. How can I count that number of input.

For example,

```
largest_so_far =  None 
smallest_so_far = "+inf" 

while True:

    value = raw_input(">")
    if value == "done":
        break

    try: 
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError: 
        print "invalid input"
        continue

    if value > largest_so_far:      
            largest_so_far = value
    if value < smallest_so_far:
            smallest_so_far = value
```

Comment: Can you show an example of that loop? Depending of the implementation, a `.size` could be enough.. Or a counter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple counter :

```
largest_so_far =  float('-inf') 
smallest_so_far = float('inf')
i = 0
while True:

    value = raw_input(">")
    if value == "done":
        break

    try: 
        value = float(value)
        i = i + 1
    except ValueError: 
        print "invalid input"
        continue

    if value > largest_so_far:      
            largest_so_far = value
    if value < smallest_so_far:
            smallest_so_far = value
```

The value of i will be the amount of inputs given by the user, minus the `done`. You can add it by moving the incrementation above the `if`.

If you don't know what a counter is, I strongly recommend that you **learn more before coding**. How do you know to use `try` statements and no counters? Have you done this code yourself?

Using code from the Internet is not a problem, but you need to understand it. :-)

Comment: Actually I knew about counter but i thought there would be some other way like what we use to count.list(). I have taken help from [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098514/print-the-result-as-soon-as-user-input-done) to write above code but not copied I have rewritten it in my own way :-)

Comment: @Freddy understand that this is not an accusation, just an advice just-in-case. You have no list to count - this is why I've asked to see your loop, counting would have worked.

Comment: I think the OP requires `float('inf')` and `float('-'inf')` as the base values - `None `will cause issues if run in Python 3.x when comparing to a `float` type and `'+inf'` is just a string (in 2.x - it just has the side effect of appearing to work - although in 3.x - again, you'll get an exception)...  Also.... the counter is incremented whether or not it's a valid `float` - so the amount of `value != 'done'` is being counted rather than the count of valid numbers...